# Fade website Background On Menu Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

You will see on the link below that if you interact with the main menu system then a transition effect happens to the body of the website [This website](http://www.beaverbrooks.co.uk/)

What is this called and how can can it be implemented into a website?

Comment: You can do it with a background-image on hover or an opacity.

Comment: It's called a page takeover. Basically you have a div that covers all of the body content of the page with a transparent background color. The div is hidden by default and then it is toggled to display when someone hovers over a menu item.(Not sure if this is exactly how the website you linked is doing it, but it's one way).

Comment: Do you have any example code of how this would be implemented, Thanks?

Comment: This should get you started: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tex3hhjr/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple **[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/y3kryn44/)** illustrating the concept.

**basic HTML:**

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="menu">menu menu menu</div>
<h1>headline</h1>
<p>hello there, I am page content</p>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $('.menu').on('mouseover', function() {
        $('.overlay').show();  //show overlay when menu hovered
    });
    $('.menu').on('mouseout', function() {
        $('.overlay').hide();   //hide overlay when cursor leaves menu
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.menu {
    width: 100%;
    background: #001fa4;
    color: #fff;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: 200;
    position: relative;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;   //overlay element is hidden until jquery shows it
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;   //absolutely position element covers entire page
    background: #939598;
    opacity: .5;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: Perfect worked great Thanks